# Why aren't my websites configured in IIS using the correct certificates?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis

My sites are similarly named:

- hi.api.domain.tld
- hi.test.domain.tld

The `.api` domain is my api and `.test` is the webapp that consumes the api.

I've got a certificate for each one but they don't seem to be working right.

One of them works fine:

> Certificate Name matches hi.test.
> Subject hi.test.redacted

The other one, however, seems to be using this same certificate (hi.test) for the hi.api site according to digicert:

> Certificate does not match name hi.api.
> Subject   hi.test.redacted

The reason why is a mystery to me because the certificate I've configured for use on the `hi.api` site is, in fact, the one for hi.api (see image below).

I'm really not a server guy so I can't even guess at the cause or how to fix. I'm not even sure what to google to find an answer here so if anyone has any insight or can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

#EDIT

Sites are [api](https://hi.api.loganyoung.co.za) and [app](https://hi.test.loganyoung.co.za)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reachable site so that we can study better the certificate? If not, please add a screenshot of the Details tab of the certificate.

Comment: Updated to add in the links [api](https://hi.api.loganyoung.co.za) and [app](https://hi.test.loganyoung.co.za). The API has no interface to show when you open it in browser but if you run a get on Postman to `/weatherforecast` it should send you some json data if everything works.

Comment: I can see that the certificate is for `hi.test.loganyoung.co.za`. Why do you think that it should also work for `hi.api.loganyoung.co.za`? You should perhaps have created a wildcard certificate for `*.loganyoung.co.za`.

Comment: I don't think that it should work for hi.api.loganyoung.co.za. I've got a certificate specially for the api link which I've configured in IIS for that site to use... what I'm failing to understand is why, despite the config being to use the hi.api certificate (per the image), is it using the hi.test certificate

Comment: You might have meant it for api, but you created it for test. Perhaps you should recreate the certificate with greater attention to the meaning of the fields. A wildcard certificate will be much more useful for your tests.

Comment: There's multiple solutions to this, including specifying additional DNS names in the SAN

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable "Require Server Name Indication" (SNI) on every binding if you have multiple sites using different certificates. Otherwise, changing the certificate on one site will change it on all sites.

You CAN have one domain that does not require SNI, but in this case, all other domains that use different certificates need to have SNI enabled. Just enabling SNI on all sites can save you trouble later, though. Basically, all sites that do not have SNI enabled always share the same certificate.